# Switching frames in tkinter without using lambda expressions

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Can someone explain how to change frames in tkinter on click of button without using lambda expression .
Here is  a part of the code

```
    button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne)
```

My problem is that I want to achieve a lot of other functions other than raising a new frame . All the answers on stack-overflow are using lambda expression
.What are the parameters to be sent to the new function so that it can switch frames as well as do some other activities as desired

Comment: `What are the parameters to be sent to the new function so that it can switch frames as well as do some other activities as desired?` What exactly are you trying to do? You can pass as many arguments as you want to a function/method if said function/method is set up for that.

Comment: In the new function , I want to raise a new frame as well as get text from an Entry object . Should I pass controller and parent as arguments to the new function ? which is not working

Comment: Are you trying to get text from the entry widget on the new frame or is this entry field in a different frame than the one being raised?

Comment: text from entry widget in the present frame , after the button click , a new frame should be raised

Comment: I think if you build everything in a class and place your frames within a list it would likely be easier to interact with it.

Comment: You should probably add more code here so we are not guessing at your intentions. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. Just create your own function to do whatever you want, and tie it to your button.

```
class Something(...):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.controller = controller
        ...
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.go_to_start)
        ...
    def go_to_start(self):
        ...
        self.controller.show_frame(PageOne)
        ...
```

Comment: Here  , self.controller gives error as 'Something ' has no controller member

Comment: @SuhasBobby: you just need to save the controller in your `__init__`. You could pass the controller in via lambda, but you explicitly said you don't want to use lambda.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/c7ddR This is giving some kind of KeyError. I don't want to use lambda because only a single line of code can be written in it

Comment: @SuhasBobby change `command=self.printhashtag()` to `command=self.printhashtag` without the `()`. When you are not using a lambda expression you will cause the program to call the method as soon as the button is created during the initialization of your program if you use `()` in your command.

Comment: @SuhasBobby: there's a difference between what I showed (`command=self.go_to_start`) and what your error shows (`command=self.printhashtag()`). Notice the lack of `()` in my example.

Comment: Thank you so much . This worked! I had noticed it I thought since no parameters were being sent in that function we could omit `()`

Comment: @SuhasBobby you need to omit `()` from the command regardless. There are other ways to pass parameters but if you are just using command to call a function/method you cannot use `()` as it will try to run it instead of providing a reference to the function/method.